# Actionscript 3: Pausing a game

Tags: actionscript-3, frame-rate

Hey so I'm working on pausing my game. I have it almost working, but there's a couple malfunctions that I can't seem to understand.

Basically I have some code (below) that pauses the frame rate and then resumes the frame rate. Both snippets of code work correctly individually, but when put together, if I press "p" it instantly cycles through both snippets of code, effectively only executing the second one (I put traces in and it shows that both codes are being executed when I press "p" once.)

So my first and primary question is how do I get this to work? I just want to execute one snippet of the code when "p" is pressed to pause the game, and then after that occurs, be able to press "p" again and execute the other snippet.

My second question is...why when I trace the frame rate does it say it is 0.01 instead of 0? Found this sort of interesting....Anyways, here's the code. Tell me if you need more context, but I don't think you will.

```
        if (stage.frameRate == 30)
        {
            if (keyboardEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.P)
            {
                dispatchEvent(new NavigationEvent(NavigationEvent.PAUSEGAME));
                stage.frameRate = 0;
                checkIfPaused = true;
                trace("pause game");
                trace(stage.frameRate);
            }
        }
        if (stage.frameRate == 0.01)
        {
            if (keyboardEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.P)
            {
                stage.frameRate = 30;
                dispatchEvent(new NavigationEvent(NavigationEvent.RESUMEGAME));
                checkIfPaused = false;
                trace("resume game");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're trying to pause in your game? Is it a popular engine (like Flixel), is it Greensock TweenLite/TweenMax, is it your own custom timer? There's no global PAUSE command in ActionScript (at least as far as I know), you have to implement it yourself. This could mean having all your objects track a global PAUSE variable, or pausing a TweenEngine, or overriding the time deltas to zero, or combination of everything.
PS.: I've never seen anyone attempt it with the stage.frameRate property, I think that would be bad practice.

Comment: well bad practice or not, I got it to work (if you saw my answer to the question). Plus, I wasn't wondering about HOW to pause, I was just wondering specifically why it was executing both parts of my if statement, so all that you were talking about is a bit extraneous for this post =p. But...I am using a timer to order my events. So perhaps it would be better practice to just pause the timer somehow, but for now this is working

Comment: One example on why pausing by setting the global fps can be undesired is that it can interfere with other things that you may not want. Such as what you have a pause menu that contains animated elements that need to be animated, or an item menu that the user needs to interact with that has animated elements (such as cursors) while only the main game is paused, and so forth.

Comment: Hmm very true. Well luckily the game I'm designing is very simplistic so this will do for now, but I definitely see how this would get in the way with more complex games.

Comment: Well bigp, looks like you were definitely right. As soon as I uploaded the swf to a free hoster, for some reason my pause function just didn't work right, even though it worked fine when I exported it within actionscript. But I was able to fix it by just stopping my timer instead, so no big deal =p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out. I just added else if instead of if for the second snippet and now it works =), but if anyone can answer my question about the frame rate being 0.01 in a nice fashion I'll give the answer to you

Comment: According to the adobe doc, valid values for frame rate is limited between 0.01 and 1000. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#frameRate But aside from that, I wonder if technically having 0 fps would cause the swf to freeze. Say there is code on the frame that meant to execute and 0 fps means no frames are being run, then it would cause the code to not run? =b

Comment: That was my guess as to why it couldn't be exactly 0 =p